# render_to_string from another controller's action.

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I used:

```
render_to_string(:controller=>:controllerName,:action=>:actionName)
```

but this only gives me the content of header and footer and not the actual content of that specific page.

Is there any other way?

Thanks

Comment: what exactly are you trying to inspect?

Comment: I just need the page source of a controller's action in another controller's action. I can't use any gems like nokogiri, etc

Answer (score 1):

I have used

```
@var = render_to_string(:file => "view_folder/index", :layout => false).to_json
```

to get data from render_to_string, and it works fine..

Answer (score 1):

`@var = render_to_string(:template => "controller/action", :layout => false)`

Comment: Please explain why this line will solve the problem!